# Ghostery extension exception: 'failed to redirect a network request to ... because another extension (Privacy Badger) redirected it to ...'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, privacy-protection, ghostery

[image]

I have installed both Ghostery and Privacy Badger extension in google chrome.

This error (as seen in the screenshot)

```
    This extension failed to redirect a network request to 
data:application/javascript;base64,...

 because another extension (Privacy Badger) redirected it to 
data:application/javascript;base64,...
```

starts to show very frequently lately. I think it also slows down chrome.

My questions are:

1) Is there any easy way to fix this redirect error?

2) Does it make sense to have both extension installed? Sometimes I observed that Ghostery covers more trackers than Privacy Badger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From discussion at: https://www.reddit.com/r/ublock/comments/3zjkos/ublock_and_ghostery_extension_error_in_chrome/

The consensus seems to be that uBlock (similar to Privacy Badger) serves the same purpose as Ghostery. I, like the OP in that thread, prefer Ghostery as the UI is easier to comprehend and apply granular changes.

The thread also suggests some specific changes to allow Google Analytics may resolve the error.